# Union to Intersection

Tags: typescript

While skimming through the [TypeScript challenges](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges), I came across a particularly interesting one:  [How to turn a union to an intersection](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/00055-hard-union-to-intersection/README.md).

Unable to figure it out myself, I turned to the solutions where I found a great approach [here](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/122) and an even greater explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type) by @jcalz.

The only problem in my way was this [question](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/122#issuecomment-696823460): effectively a user tried to break down the solution in multiple separate statements and, to my surprise, the result was not the same. Instead of `foo & bar` we were getting `foo | bar`. Putting the solution back together as a "one-liner" the result gets "restored": `foo & bar`.

```js
// Type definition
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (arg: U) => any : never) extends ((arg: infer I) => void) 
  ? I 
  : never;

// As expected  ('foo' & 'bar' is never)
type I = UnionToIntersection<'foo' | 'bar'>;  // never

// Let's break-down `UnionToIntersection`

type A = 'foo' | 'bar';

type B = A extends any ? (arg: A) => any : never // (arg: A) => any;

// This should have been 'foo' & 'bar' (never) just like `type I` 
type C = B extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never //  'foo' | 'bar'
```

What's going on here? Shouldn't `type I` and `type C` be the same?

Comment: `B` is `(arg: 'foo' | 'bar') => void` and it is inferring `I` to `'foo' | 'bar'` correctly

Comment: But why? Shouldn't it be `((arg: 'foo') => any) | ((arg: 'bar') => any)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> effectively a user tried to break down the solution in multiple separate statements

The user made a mistake. In the original type, `U` is a generic type which gets [distributed](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) in the conditional.

In `B`, you use `A` which is not a generic type. No distribution takes place.

If we modify `B` to also have a generic type `U` (which we just default to be `A`), we will see the same result `never`.

```
type B<U = A> = U extends any ? (arg: U) => any : never 
type C = B extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never 
//   ^? never
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBUE8AcFNQCawGYEsB2qAuqD26BYAKCxngFVN9xcBJdLWAJwGdYBjHfAHnID5QAXlAAKcqFgAPRugQtQAQ3SRQAflEKmAcwBcocgEohApSr3pYAN2ZGpMuaJGbdoDMmahaRwQMu5UCEbEoGqeoMGg5lbMANzExCCgAILyUnCcsAiggLwbgLI7ogDkyLi4BaAAZKAFAEaaZajyFtZMBsSkcGHClHjoNPSMrBxc6NxFJWUAPlW1TAV8MSGJTczxRIkAMrBYBfLVTLAKANYAtAi4AO7ooAAG3dR0DMxsnD3Xq%203wSUJVxaWgUzU6nEiG0yKAAEK8b5JARdCTSWCyeSmUJObR6QzGRTKSKgZZMUCJNEuJLeEzKYEJMDgAAWDVALBpuAArgAbLI0hTWUDVWCIn7jCrTOqifFGABWzJYWFArNQh3g1w%20nmuoEAfBuAel3QR0AMLfcHw%20zyETEvRuDxeLF%20AJGdS0XH4wlgAV-AEzApAA)

Comment: OMG! That's it! Well spotted! Thank you!

Comment: One last thing: I noticed that changing `C` to this: `type C<U> = U extends ((arg: infer I) => void) ? I : never;` and then doing `type Result = C<B>` will once again return `'foo' | 'bar'`. Do you know why? Thanks again!

Comment: @stratis - Its pretty much the opposite problem of before. `B` was not generic, so no distribution which means we have `((arg: "foo") => any) | ((arg: "bar") => any)
extends infer I` => `I` is intersection of `"foo" & "bar"`. If `B` is generic, we have  `((arg: "foo") => any) extends infer I` and `((arg: "bar") => any) extend infer I` where `I` will be a union of both results

Comment: Could also use `A extends infer X ? X extends X ? ... : ...`. Although `X` isn't really a "generic" type it still works.

Answer (score 2):

[Distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) work for (naked) parameter types.

Replace your

```ts
type B = A extends any ? (arg: A) => any : never // (arg: A) => any;
```

with

```ts
type BT<T> = T extends any ? (arg: T) => any : never;
type B = BT<A>
```

to see the difference